# Images are getting cut off when the website is viewed in a small screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, parallax

I have a problem where my images are getting cut off when the height or the width is decreased. I need to make it responsive so I it isn't helping.

I have tried to use media queries but its still not working.
Code - [Github](https://github.com/Binary-Bytes/Responsive-Parallax-Website)
Sample Website - [GitHub Pages](https://binary-bytes.github.io/Responsive-Parallax-Website/)

Thanks.

Comment: Looking for example at the mouse it has height and width both set and set as %s of the height and width of the container respectively. Try keeping those settings but add object-fit: contain (in this case to the #mouse styling). This will ensure the whole figure will be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem is due to the inconstant aspect ratio of the height and width of the images. In the case of the mouse and the gruffalo, both the width and height are set to a percentage of the display resolution. The aspect ratio of the display is typically different compared to the aspect ratio of the images. To fix this, one of the attributes (width or height) should be set to auto in order to take in account the aspect resolution of the images.

The problem with the mouse and the gruffalo can be solved like this.

```css
section #mouse {
    top: 38%;
    left: 10%;
    height: 30%;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 10;
}
section #gruffalo {
    top: 41%;
    left: 75%;
    height: 30%;
    width: auto;
}
```

The code below fixes the issue of the images being cut off by maintaining aspect ratio.

I hope this response has been of help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

This because you have defined a `height`, `width`, and `object-fit: cover` for your images. Your height and width are both percentages of the window size so they will not always match the aspect ratio of the image. `object-fit: cover` means that if the height and width of an image do not match the image's aspect ratio, it will scale to the larger of the two and cut off the ends of the image that do not fit.

In order to prevent the images being cut off, you will need to either

- eliminate `object-fit: cover`, or
- eliminate either the `height` or `width` variable (so that the other one will be automatically determined)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in this css:

```
section #mouse {
    top: 38%;
    left: 10%;
    height: 30%;
    width: 15%;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

when you set width 15% the image will be cut when width is decreased.
the same reason for height...
Using percentage in height or width will make it cut.

I think you can use `object-fit: contain;` and  `object-position: center;` in this image css and convert one of `width` or `height` to `max-width` or `max-height`.
The same thing for *#gruffalo*